# Adding an Array to a JSON Object and sending it to server

Tags: javascript, json

I have an Object into a `.json` file and it includes just an Array.

Now I would like to get a word from the user using `prompt`, and add it to this Array; you can see the codes below :

```
function addWord() {
    let myWords = getWords();
    let newWord = prompt("What word would you like to be added to your list?", "");
    myWords.push(newWord);
    let myWordsJson = JSON.stringify(myWords);
    let xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.open("GET", "words.json?wordsArray=" + myWordsJson);
    xhr2.send();
}
```

And here is `getWords()` function :

```
function getWords() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "words.json", false);
    xhr.send();
    let myCode = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    return myCode["wordsArray"];
}
```

I have debugged my code and there is no problem with receiving the Array from the server and adding the new word, but then I can not send the new Array to the `words.json` file.

here is `words.json` :

```
{"wordsArray" : ["hello", "pencil", "school", "tooth", "family", "class"]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by cannot send the new array to the file? Do you own the backend that handles these requests? What does it do with your GET request?

Comment: Are you trying to edit a file on the server using a simple GET request ? If the server doesn't provide capabilities for you to edit such file it is impossible

Comment: how can I handle that? is WebApi a good choice?

Answer (score -1):

we have to push single single word into the array

```js
 let newWord = "What word would you like to be added to your list?";
 myWords['wordsArray'].push(newWord);
```

or if we have another array of words to be pushed we can use a for loop to as shown below

```js
 let newWord = ["What word would you like to be added to your list?"];
         
      for(let i = 0; i < newWord.length ; i++) {   
         myWords['wordsArray'].push(newWord[i]);
         }
```